# Azure DevOps, need to populate number of team members into a custom fields

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

In Azure devops, I have a team and there are lot of members in it. In Epic I created a new custom field called "No. of Resources" and it need to be auto-populate the number of team members to the field "No. of Resources".

Answer (score 0):

> need to be auto-populate the number of team members to the field "No.
> of Resources"

I am afraid this is currently not possible in azure devops. The process rule in the organization settings does not provide an action that can obtain the number of team members.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion) site , which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it.

[image]